# Why is this python "War" card game freezing after only a few games?

Tags: python, playing-cards

Basically, I'm trying to test how the order of the cards in a players hand affects how often they win, but I run the program and the score will sometimes get stuck at player one alternating between 27 & 26 cards in hand, while player two alternates between 25 & 26 cards in hand and it just sticks like that.

```
import random
import sys

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit, value):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        self.name = str(self.rank) + " of " + self.suit

def create_deck():
    suit = ['Spades', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
    rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen',    'King', 'Ace']
    deck = []
    num = 2
    for i in suit:
        for x in rank:
            deck.append(Card(x, i, num))
            num = num + 1
        num = 2

    return sorted(deck, key=lambda k: random.random())

def deal_cards(deck):  
    x = 0
    i = 0
    player1 = []
    player2 = []
    while i < len(deck):
        if x == 0:
            player1.append(deck[i])
            x = 1
        else:
            player2.append(deck[i])
            x = 0
        i += 1
    return player1, player2

def game():
    pl1wins = 0
    pl2wins = 0
    while (pl1wins + pl2wins) <= 50: 
        deck = create_deck()
        players = deal_cards(deck)
        player1 = players[0]
        player2 = players[1]

        player1 = sorted(player1, key=lambda card: card.value)
        war = []

        turns = 0
        while len(player1) > 0 and len(player2) > 0:
            turns = turns + 1
            #print turns
            #print str(len(player1))+ " : " + str(len(player2))
            if (len(player1) + len(player2)) > 52:
                print "Oh NO!"
                sys.exit()
            war = []
            war.append(player1[0])
            war.append(player2[0])

            player1.remove(player1[0])
            player2.remove(player2[0])
            if war[0].value > war[1].value:
                #print "Player 1 wins the " + war[1].name
                i = 0
                n = len(war)
                while i < n:
                    player1.append(war[0])
                    war.remove(war[0])
                    i = i + 1

            elif war[0].value < war[1].value:
                #print "Player 2 wins the " + war[0].name
                i = 0
                n = len(war)
                while i < n:
                    player2.append(war[0])
                    war.remove(war[0])
                    i = i + 1

            elif war[0].value == war[1].value:
                if len(player1) == 0:
                    player1.append(war[0])
                    war.remove(war[0])
                    if player1[0].value == player2[0].value:
                        player1[0].value = 0
                if len(player2) == 0:
                    player2.append(war[1])
                    war.remove(war[1])
                    if player1[0].value == player2[0].value:
                        player2[0].value = 0
                while len(war) > 0:
                    #print "The cards have tied, war will commence"

                    i = 0
                    for i in range(3):
                        if len(player1) > 1:
                            war.append(player1[0])
                            player1.remove(player1[0])

                        if len(player2) > 1:   
                            war.append(player2[0])
                            player2.remove(player2[0])

                    if player1[0].value > player2[0].value:
                        war.append(player1[0])
                        war.append(player2[0])
                        player1.remove(player1[0])
                        player2.remove(player2[0])
                        i = 0
                        n = len(war)
                        while i < n:
                            player1.append(war[0])
                            war.remove(war[0])
                            i = i + 1      
                    elif player1[0].value < player2[0].value:
                        war.append(player1[0])
                        war.append(player2[0])
                        player1.remove(player1[0])
                        player2.remove(player2[0])
                        i = 0
                        n = len(war)
                        while i < n:
                            player2.append(war[0])
                            war.remove(war[0])
                            i = i + 1

        #print turns
        if len(player1) != 0:
            print "Player1 wins!"
            pl1wins = pl1wins + 1
        elif len(player2) != 0:
            print "Player2 wins!"
            pl1wins = pl2wins + 1
    print pl1wins + " versus " + pl2wins
game()
```

Comment: "Gets stuck"? What happens? Do you get an error? Have you tried debugging to see if it's entering an infinite loop?

Comment: It would be valuable for you to break this out into methods so that you can really see what's going on.  You've got a lot of duplicated logic, and the likelihood is that it's getting hung up in that duplicated flow.

Comment: Wild guess: some small percentage of War games (say, 5%), never end because the cards are arranged just right so that one player never gains a permanent advantage over the other one.

Comment: There are possible infinite games in War, provided you do not switch the order in which player's cards are added to the bottom of the winning player's deck (i.e. *always* opponent's card first, then yours or vice versa). [See this MathOverflow discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11503/does-war-have-infinite-expected-length). Basically for some deals, the game never ends. You could add [occasional switching to the order that cards are returned to the bottom of the deck to make it finite](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1371).

Comment: I'm suspicious of those `player1[0].value = 0` and `player2[0].value = 0` lines you have. Those changes are permanent, even when the card is returned to a player's deck and played later.

Comment: @Kevin I looked into the problem, but, as it turns out when it reaches that point where the value of the card is forced to change, that signifies that the game ends (because the reach a war in which one of the players is not able to place down any cards in the war) and when the game restarts it recreates all the cards with their previous values. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Thanks @Engineero for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Engineero for your comment:

> There are possible infinite games in War, provided you do not switch the order in which player's cards are added to the bottom of the winning player's deck (i.e. always opponent's card first, then yours or vice versa). See this MathOverflow discussion. Basically for some deals, the game never ends. You could add occasional switching to the order that cards are returned to the bottom of the deck to make it finite. –  Engineero

That led me to this solution:

Basically, I randomized which card was put in the pile first as such:

```
        if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
            war.append(player2[0])
            war.append(player1[0])
        else:
            war.append(player1[0])
            war.append(player2[0])
```

And this fixed the problem perfectly.